# Use Standard Camera Button on a Camera Overlay (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, button, camera, overlay

I am using an `Overlay` on the camera views in my app. Problem is, I want to use the standard Camera Button - the long oval button that you tap to take a picture.

Is there a way to add the oval camera button to my overlay?

Comment: Could you just take a screenshot of the standard camera app on your phone and then use an image program to cut out just the button?

Comment: Take 2 screenshots, one while pressing, one normal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a good way to accomplish this so I created an overlay with a large button with a camera icon on it, but it does not look like the standard camera button.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the overlay view size so that it doesn't hide the camera button toolbar.

Comment: That does not work. If you set picker.showsCameraControls = YES , then I can't control which view appears after the user takes the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Just set userInteractionEnabled to false for your overlayview. Then all interaction with the camera will behave like it did before.

//edit: also make the overlayview transparent. on top of that view add the view, you want to show up as overlayview, but size it as small as needed to not hide the default camera button. if you want to change you're overlay in the photo-preview-view, see my answer here: [camera overlay view - just for preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081872/camera-overlay-view-just-for-preview/8898483#8898483)