# how to create paginated camera overlays

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay

I am new to iphone development, and i am wondering how would i go about placing a page control as an overlay for the camera, so that a user could swipe and different overlays would be shown for each page? This would have similar features as the [The Sampler by Converse](http://images.freshnessmag.com/wp-content/uploads//2010/12/Sampler_5.jpg).

1. Firstly there will be the camera
2. on top will be a scroll view (paginated)
3. each page will hold an image that is overlayed over the camera

4.(extra) i would like that image to zoomable

How would i go about writing this, or could someone point me in the write direction cause i am new to iPhone dev,

Comment: Can you elaborate on the definition of overlays? What do you expect to see when you swipe page?

Comment: I see what you mean now. If you're using iOS5 there are AV Foundation improvements that you can't take advantage of. If you have a developer account, take a look at the WWDC 2011 videos. Also, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081872/camera-overlay-view-just-for-preview

Comment: ok i would like to develop for iOS4 ... i will look at the link other answer now

Answer (score 3):

You could use a UIScrollView with paging enabled, as someone else noted. There are some examples out there already of how to do this. Check this one out: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser.

My best suggestion would definitely be to checkout the source for the PhotoScroller app by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason. After the first page scroll, the UIScrollView (which is the cameraOverlayView) stops receiving touch events. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `UIScrollView` to your view and add the images as subviews to your picker. Make sure you enabled Paging on the scrollview as well.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the [cameraOverlayView property of UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

The cameraOverlayView will essentially be a paginated scrollview, you can follow this sample code to see how to create and use cameraOverlayView:

[PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

Play with [OverlayViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/OverlayViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-OverlayViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) in the above code and you'll achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

For the zoomable image, you just would add a scrollview and display the image in it. The UIScrollView delegate has this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale.
```